# visible? returns false for visible element if parent is hidden

Tags: browser, watir

Watir's `visible?` method iterates up the DOM element tree and checks if any of the parent elements has visibility attribute set to hidden. 
If any of the parents is hidden then `visible?` returns `false` and that's it.

In case of the following HTML:

```
<div id="parent" style="display: block; visibility:hidden;">
  <div id="child" style="display: block; visibility:visible;">
    Visibility Check.
  </div>
</div>
```

`visible?` will return `false` because "parent" div is hidden.

However the div is actually visible in the browser.

Is it a feature in Watir and I shall live with it or is there a nice workaround here?

Comment: I assume you are using watir-classic? Given that it seems to work properly in watir-webdriver, I would suggest it is a bug with watir-classic - you should log it at https://github.com/watir/watir-classic.

Comment: hey Justin, thanks for the reply.
indeed i'm using watir-classic because watir-webdriver is not an option.
I also think it's a bug, but wanted to ask first because it seems to me unreal that visible? can have a bug.

Comment: What does it actually mean by the spec if ````display```` is ````block````, but ````visibility```` is ````hidden````?

Comment: Hi Jarmo,

a definition from here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html  
hidden
    The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout. Furthermore, descendants of the element will be visible if they have 'visibility: visible'.

Comment: Hi guys, any update on this? Shall I somehow make a workaround for this or will Watir change in the future?

Comment: Show your code, what have you tried? and share more of your HTML or website page which you are trying to automate.